# CSS match elements with ANY attribute

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a CSS selector that matches elements that have ANY attribute?

`<div>`, `<p>`, and `<h2>` would not match but `<div class="important">`, `<p align="left">` and `<h2 id="rt0">` would.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without listing all attributes out

Comment: @chazsolo Note that `*[foo]` is the same as `[foo]`.

Comment: I feel like this should have a hacky hidden solution, but I've been searching for ~40min now and I can't find any loophole or workaround. I WILL NOT GIVE UP

Comment: @MatheusAvellar By CSS specification, this isn't possible with `[*] { ... }`. I highly doubt that there's a way to select all attributes unless you list them.

Comment: @chazsolo: That carries an assumption that only the attributes you list will ever be used, and doesn't take into account custom data attributes. You might as well say that it's "technically possible" in a document that only uses the id, class and title attributes, with [id], [class], [title] as the selector-list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such selector.<sup>1</sup>

Such a selector has been proposed or requested a number of times [over](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2009Feb/0676.html) the [last](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Mar/0663.html) several [years](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2014Jun/0004.html), and out of these the *only* time [someone even bothered to suggest a use case](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2009Feb/0713.html), it's one that has no relevance to CSS at all:

> this selector would be useful for debugging purposes in order to verify in complex layouts whether an element has attributes or not (instead of using DOM's hasAttributes() method).

Even if this *was* your use case (which, like the other threads on www-style, you haven't stated at all in your question), the fact remains that no such selector exists.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>There is [`::attr(*)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-nonelement/#attribute-node-selector), but that selects *attribute nodes*, not element nodes based on attributes (which, ostensibly, is what the asker is interested in). Completely different things.</sub>

Comment: My use case is in XHTML for attributes in non-HTML namespaces. I want to underline all tei: elements that have attributes. I too doubt there would be much need in plain old HTML.

Answer (score 4):

**As of today (Feb 27 2017), it isn't possible.**

Some insane people might go out and list every single official attribute and put it in a CSS rule ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/657srs01/)). If you can't be bothered to visit that link, here it is:

```
[aria-activedescendant], [aria-atomic], [aria-controls], [aria-describedby], [aria-dropeffect], [aria-haspopup], [aria-label], [aria-labelledby], [aria-live], [aria-multiselectable], [aria-owns], [aria-readonly], [aria-relevant], [aria-required], [aria-sort], [aria-valuemax], [aria-valuemin], [aria-valuenow], [onabort], [onautocomplete], [onautocompleteerror], [onDOMContentLoaded], [onafterprint], [onafterscriptexecute], [onbeforeprint], [onbeforescriptexecute], [onbeforeunload], [onblur], [oncancel], [onchange], [onclick], [onclose], [onconnect], [oncontextmenu], [onerror], [onfocus], [onhashchange], [oninput], [oninvalid], [onlanguagechange], [onload], [onloadend], [onloadstart], [onmessage], [onoffline], [ononline], [onopen], [onpagehide], [onpageshow], [onpopstate], [onprogress], [onreadystatechange], [onreset], [onselect], [onshow], [onsort], [onstorage], [onsubmit], [ontoggle], [onunload], [onloadeddata], [onloadedmetadata], [oncanplay], [onplaying], [onplay], [oncanplaythrough], [onseeked], [onseeking], [onstalled], [onsuspend], [ontimeupdate], [onvolumechange], [onwaiting], [ondurationchange], [onemptied], [onunhandledrejection], [onrejectionhandled], [onafterprint], [onbeforeprint], [onbeforeunload], [onhashchange], [onlanguagechange], [onpopstate], [onrejectionhandled], [onstorage], [onunhandledrejection], [onunload], [accept], [accept-charset], [accesskey], [action], [align], [alt], [aria], [async], [autocomplete], [autofocus], [autoplay], [autosave], [bgcolor], [border], [buffered], [challenge], [charset], [checked], [cite], [class], [code], [codebase], [color], [cols], [colspan], [content], [contenteditable], [contextmenu], [controls], [coords], [data], [datetime], [default], [defer], [dir], [dirname], [disabled], [download], [draggable], [dropzone], [enctype], [for], [form], [formaction], [headers], [height], [hidden], [high], [href], [hreflang], [http-equiv], [icon], [id], [integrity], [ismap], [itemprop], [keytype], [kind], [label], [lang], [language], [list], [loop], [low], [manifest], [max], [maxlength], [media], [method], [min], [multiple], [muted], [name], [novalidate], [open], [optimum], [pattern], [ping], [placeholder], [poster], [preload], [radiogroup], [readonly], [rel], [required], [reversed], [rows], [rowspan], [sandbox], [scope], [scoped], [seamless], [selected], [shape], [size], [sizes], [slot], [span], [spellcheck], [src], [srcdoc], [srclang], [srcset], [start], [step], [style], [summary], [tabindex], [target], [title], [type], [usemap], [value], [width], [wrap] {  ...  }
```

But then again, who'd want that, that's like 2500 characters long.

Even with all that wasted potential gone into attribute research, there are still some things that extensive list doesn't cover, such as custom `data-*` attributes or even weird "[HTML Microdata](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#attr-itemscope)" attributes:

[image: screenshot]

*`itemscope`? `itemtype`? What does that even **do**?!*

So, unfortunately, as of today, you're gonna have to find an alternative solution to whatever problem is in your hands.

Comment: a.k.a. I gave up searching